# Undefined control sequence for tikzpicture bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I am getting  `Undefined control sequence.` error for the following tikzpicture code. it's generated at `\end{axis}`. I have checked the code multiple times but coundn't figure out the error. Please note that preamble incudes following packages.
`\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `\usepackage{tikz,times}` as well.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    symbolic x coords={
        A,
        B,
        C
        },
    xtick=data,
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1
        },
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\normal},
   nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
    
\addplot coordinates {
    (A, 23) 
    (B, 16)
    (C, 68) 
    };

\addplot coordinates {
    (A,  84)
    (B, 94) 
    (C, 97) 

};
    \legend{Legend 1, Legend 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}``
```

appreciate any support I can get for this.

Comment: You need to say `font=\normalfont`, not `font=\normal`.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @cis That did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved in the comments.